# any one knows in which file can I add a feature to block specific site in a chromium browser?

Tags: chromium

I am custemizing chromium browser and, I need to add a code to block a specific site or lists of sites. When I try it in chromium\src\content\browser\web_contents\web_contents_impl.cc and I rebuild, the functionality intended to work is not working. the version I am working on is version 115.0.57798.0

I tried in chromium\src\content\browser\web_contents\web_contents_impl.cc, but I need to Know another file to update for my functionality